# Converting a float variable to string

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm trying to convert a variable whose value changes however the value is usually to one decimal place e.g. 0.5. I'm trying to change this variable to 0.50. I'm using this code but when I run the program it says `TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly`

Here is my code:

```
while topup == 2:
    credit = credit + 0.5
    credit = str(credit)
    credit = '%.2f' % credit
    print("You now have this much credit £", credit)
    vending(credit)
```

Comment: That's not the error I'm getting. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: The error is actually that you're passing a string in `'%.2f' % credit` `TypeError: a float is required` for python 3 and `TypeError: float argument required, not str` for python 2.

Comment: @Kevin I'm using Python 3.4

Comment: @IsaacGSivaa Not a duplicate, though the OP might notice that as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
while topup == 2:
    credit = float(credit) + 0.5
    credit = '%.2f' % credit
    print("You now have this much credit £", credit)
    vending(credit)
```

the problem is you cannot float format a string

```
"%0.2f"%"3.45"  # raises error
```

instead it expects a number

```
"%0.2f"%3.45   # 0k
"%0.2f"%5   # also ok
```

so when you call `str(credit)` it breaks the format string right below (that incidentally also casts credit back to a string)

incidentally you should really only do this when you print

```
credit = 1234.3
print("You Have : £%0.2f"%credit)
```

in general you want your credit to be a numeric type so that you can do math with it

Comment: Is there anyway I can solve my problem any other way by not using str(credit)?